# Conditions for two limiting distributions to be independent

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

Let two sequences of random variables $X_n \Rightarrow \mathcal{L}_X$ and $Y_n \Rightarrow \mathcal{L}_Y$, where $\Rightarrow$ denotes convergence in law, can anyone give a general condition on $X_n$, $Y_n$ for $\mathcal{L}_X$ and $\mathcal{L}_Y$ to be independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are independent for all $n\ge 0$, $(X_n,Y_n)\Rightarrow \mathcal{L}_X\otimes \mathcal{L}_Y$. Then one may construct a coupling $(X',Y')$ s.t. $\mathcal{L}_{X'}=\mathcal{L}_X$, $\mathcal{L}_{Y'}=\mathcal{L}_Y$, and $X'$ and $Y'$ are independent.

Comment: Is there any link or reference for the proof of this result?

Comment: @user128422 What kind of proof are you looking for? It is a simple fact.

Comment: My bad, I was just wondering how can we construct $(X´,Y´)$. I guess i will think about it